# If $S_{n} =\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}$ converges to $L$, prove that $S_{n-1}$ converges to $L$.

Tags: calculus

If $S_{n} = a_{1} + a_{2} + ... + a_{n}$ converges to $L$, prove that $S_{n-1}$ converges to $L$.

This is just a personal question I had mainly because in the proof of the nth term test, one arrives at the conclusion that $a_{n}= S_{n}- S_{n-1} = L - L = 0$.

I did not mean for this post to be a bad question. I really thought the proposition I wrote as my first sentence was something that can actually be proven.

Comment: This is a general property of converging sequences.

Comment: You don't have the right definition of $S_n.$ Please edit.

Comment: Once again I can't understand why this question's been closed. This seems to be completely whimsical sometimes...

Answer (score 1):

$$S_{n-1}=S_n-a_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} L-0=L$$